# How to achieve having 2 contorls on the same level in XAML layout in WPF?

Tags: wpf, layout

I'm trying to make a layout of label, button and rich text box so the label and the button would be above the text box but in different sides.

I tried this:

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
        <StackPanel>
            <DockPanel>
                <Label>some text</Label>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"  Width="30px">x</Button>
            </DockPanel>
            <RichTextBox Height="100px"></RichTextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

As a result:
[image: As a result:]

Also I thought it might work:

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                <Label>some text</Label>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30px">x</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <RichTextBox Height="100px"></RichTextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

But it did not:
[image: But it did not:]

It's easy with the label and it's where i want it to be, but what can i do to place the button above the right corner of the text box? I also have seen RenderTransform property but I'm not sure if this is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid>
                <RichTextBox Height="100px" ></RichTextBox>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Label VerticalAlignment="Top">some text</Label>
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30px" VerticalAlignment="Top">x</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```